# ¿Existe alguna forma de que actualizar el valor de una tabla usando de referencia otra automaticamente?

Tags: sql, oracle, apex

Tengo que crear las tablas necesarias para el manejo de una pagina de streaming tipo Netflix. La pagina cuenta con una tabla "principal" llamada plataforma que sirve para guardar distintos servidores y las relaciones necesarias entre las plataformas y los contenidos.

A la hora de crear los contenidos, estos contenidos están separados en Series y películas, cada uno con su tabla correspondiente.

Tabla Plataforma:

```
 CREATE TABLE Plataforma(
    DirecServidor NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    NumeroSubs INT,
    NumeroContenidos INT,
    Precio NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (Precio>=0)
);
```

Tabla Serie y tabla Película:

```
CREATE TABLE Serie(
    IDContenido NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Titulo VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
    NTemporadas NUMBER,
    DirecServidor NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (DirecServidor) REFERENCES Plataforma(DirecServidor)
);
CREATE TABLE Pelicula(
    IDContenido NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Titulo VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
    Director VARCHAR(30),
    Guionista VARCHAR(30),
    Duracion NUMBER(3,2),
    DirecServidor NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (DirecServidor) REFERENCES Plataforma(DirecServidor)
);
```

El identificador de las películas y de las series se genera automáticamente si no se proporciona uno (a base de contador)

Me gustaría que la columna de numeroContenidos en la tabla plataforma cuente el numero de contenidos, tanto películas como series y que los identificadores de los contenidos vayan de acuerdo con ese numero (si hay 2 películas y una serie, al introducir una serie nueva el Id sería 4 y no 2).

Podría hacerlo si cuando llamo a la función de insert tambien hago un Update a plataforma pero no es lo que busco.
¿Hay alguna forma de que el NumeroContenidos de la Plataforma se actualice automáticamente al insertar una serie o una película?

De la misma forma ¿hay alguna forma de hacer que la Identity se genere en base a ese numero de contenidos?

Comment: Qué has intentado? Tal vez un trigger sea una buena opción

Comment: Si bien lo puedes lograr con una [secuencia](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm), es mucho mejor juntar las 4 columnas en común de Series y Películas en una sola tabla: Contenidos y tener la columna `Tipo` con valores (S)erie y (P)elicula por ejemplo. Las otras columnas que no son comunes puedes manejarlas con nulos en la misma tabla dependiendo del tipo de contenido, ó dejarlas en tablas separadas relacionadas por `IDContenido`
.

Comment: @Arriel he mirado el tema de los triggers y es justo lo que busco muchísimas gracias. No se me había ocurrido la palabra a la hora de buscar información. Lo que había intentado era simplemente actualizar la tabla a la hora de introducir contenidos pero con el trigger le puedo dar mas consistencia al proceso.

Comment: @Sal Había mirado ya las secuencias pero al final he decidido quedarme con los identity que hacen algo similar y son mas sencillos (acabo de empezar con la creación de tablas). Y respecto al contenido resulta que he revisado el diagrama ER y efectivamente series y películas son especializaciones, no se por que al pasar a tabla obvié el detalle. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución: crear una tabla adicional Contenidos que guarde los campos de ambos tipos (películas y series).
La plataforma ya no guardará el numero de contenidos y si se necesita en algún momento se podrán contar el numero de filas de la tabla contenidos

```
CREATE TABLE Plataforma(
    DirecServidor NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    NumeroSubs INT,
    Precio NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (Precio>=0)
);
```

En contenidos se guardan los datos comunes de Películas y series

```
CREATE TABLE Contenidos(
    IDContenido NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Titulo VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
    DirecServidor NUMBER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (DirecServidor) REFERENCES Plataforma(DirecServidor)

);
```

En películas y series se guardará la clave foranea del contenido que corresponda

```
CREATE TABLE Serie(
    IDContenido NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NTemporadas NUMBER,
    FOREIGN KEY (IDContenido) REFERENCES Contenidos(IDContenido)
);
CREATE TABLE Pelicula(
    IDContenido NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    Director VARCHAR(30),
    Guionista VARCHAR(30),
    Duracion NUMBER(6,2),
    FOREIGN KEY (IDContenido) REFERENCES Contenidos(IDContenido)

);
```